# how Ballassa Samuelson affects real exchange rate?

Tags: macroeconomics

I get confused. How "Balassa Samuelson effect" influences real exchange rate?

Comment: What do you mean by the *real* exchange rate?  Inflation adjusted? Purchasing-power-parity adjusted?

Comment: ppp adjusted real effective exchange rate